# Excel Formulae with Empty Values in Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on some Excel Formulae but am unable to workout a solution. My issue is as below

The value in **column E** is based on a formulae: - 
**=IF(ISBLANK(D2),C2,CONCATENATE("         ",$C$2," - ",C2))**

So when the column Value is Empty, the Row E6 has to change with the value present in E5. So the value in E6 has to be **Password Change Request - Recurring password change activity** *instead of* **Data Truncation issues - Recurring password change activity**

I have attached an Image File[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need this...

In E2

```
=IF(D2="",C2,INDEX(C$2:C2,MAX(TRUE,INDEX((D$2:D2="")*(ROW(D$2:D2)-ROW(D$2)+1),)))&" - "&C2)
```

and then copy it down.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy variable called Issue in column F with the formula:

```
=IF(D2="",C2,F1)
```

Now use the formula using reference of column F in column E:

```
=IF(D2="",C2,CONCATENATE(F2,"-",C2))
```

Refer to image for explanation:[image]